# Cannot get bibentry to work in europecv

Tags: bibentry, europecv

The title says it all.  I cannot get `bibentry` to work in `europcv`.  MWE below:

`MWE.tex`:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,nologo,notitle,notitle,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\renewcommand\refname{List of Publications}

\ecvname{Face, Cat}
\ecvfootername{C.F.}
\ecvemail{\url{cat@face.mew}}
\ecvpage{\thepage}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]

\ecvsection{Education and Degrees}
\ecvitem{2012}{\textbf{Mewsters degree}}

\ecvsection{Work Experience}
\ecvitem{June 2007 - present}{\textbf{Lying in the sun all day}}

\ecvsection{Publications and Technical Reports}
\ecvitem{$\bullet$}{\bibentry{Whiskers2016}}

\ecvsection{Research Projects}
\ecvitem{Aug - Dec 2011}{\textbf{Trying to get my tail to quit twitching while I sleep}}
\end{europecv}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{MWE.bib}
\end{document}
```

`MWE.bib`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
@article{Whiskers2016,
    author      = "Fancy Whiskers",
    title       = "How to kill your owner while they sleep",
    year        = "2016",
    note        = "In preparation"
}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Output:
[image: MWE Output]

But I want there to be a `bibentry` at the bullet point...

Comment: Hmm, I did not know it was outdated.  I had to write my cv in this class for something a while ago, and I have just maintained it in this class since.  I was hoping to not have to change classes, because that would entail re-writing everything.  But if it is out-dated, then I suppose updating is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation of `bibentry` you can read:

> These commands (`\bibentry`) may only be issued after `\nobibliography`, for
>   otherwise the reference texts are not known.

That means you have to change the order of the commands `\nobibliography` and `\bibentry` in your code.  Please see the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Whiskers2016,
  author = "Fancy Whiskers",
  title  = "How to kill your owner while they sleep",
  year   = "2016",
  note   = "In preparation",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,nologo,notitle,notitle,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\renewcommand\refname{List of Publications}

\ecvname{Face, Cat}
\ecvfootername{C.F.}
\ecvemail{\url{cat@face.mew}}
\ecvpage{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\nobibliography{\jobname} % <===========================================

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]

\ecvsection{Education and Degrees}
\ecvitem{2012}{\textbf{Mewsters degree}}

\ecvsection{Work Experience}
\ecvitem{June 2007 - present}{\textbf{Lying in the sun all day}}

\ecvsection{Publications and Technical Reports}
\ecvitem{$\bullet$}{\bibentry{Whiskers2016}} % <========================

\ecvsection{Research Projects}
\ecvitem{Aug - Dec 2011}{\textbf{Trying to get my tail to quit twitching while I sleep}}
\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]